# Missing dir /etc/kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am brand new to kubernetes. I am working on a Mac M1. Docker is already installed

I followed the aws instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-kubectl.html)

I got caught with this error:

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

This led me to instructions all over the internet that I need to copy `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` to `~/.kube/config`

This is where it gets weird. I don't have a `etc/kubernetes` directory.

**Question:** Does anyone know why and how to fix?

In addition, it turnes out that kubectl was already installed with homebrew. I uninstalled and reinstalled following aws instructions (above). This still brought no success

Any help deeply appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/kubernetes` directory is present inside the master nodes of the cluster. In case of bare-metal kubernetes , you can `SSH` into one of the nodes & copy the `admin.conf` file.

For cloud based k8s cluster like AWS's EKS, download the `admin.conf` file from the dashboard and place it `~/.kube/` folder. This [AWS EKS Kubeconfig access](https://hub.qovery.com/guides/tutorial/how-to-connect-to-your-eks-cluster-with-kubectl/) may help you

Answer (score 1):

With me, I was on a Mac. I had docker desktop installed. This seemed to include kubectl in homebrew

I traced it down to a link in usr/local/bin and renamed it to kubectl-old

Then I reinstalled kubectl, put it on my path and everything worked.

I know this is very specific to my case, but may help others.